# How to compliment audio with onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, onclick, onclicklistener

***Functionality:***

When user clicks on the "TAP ME" image button, they will be able to hear the click audio sound. Hence, when user is to tap the image button repetitively, the click audio sound will be in compliment with the user tapping of the image button.

***What has been done:***

I have managed to create onclick tap audio when user clicks on the "TAP ME" image button.

***Issue:***

Though, the click sound compliments the user onclick of the "TAP ME" image button. However, the issue arises when the user starts to spam the "TAP ME" image button. The audio will not be able to compliment the spamming of the "TAP ME" image button.

Hence, how is it possible to sync the click audio to onclick function:

I have pasted the following code for your reference:

```js
function GameStart() {
  console.log("GameStart");
  x = document.getElementById('GameStar').offsetTop;
  var audioClick = document.getElementById("click");
  //check condition if star reach bottom page limit, else continue to move down
  if (x < bottomStarLimit) {
    console.log("x:" + x);
    x = x + step;
    audioClick.play();
  }
  document.getElementById('GameStar').style.top = x + "px";
}
```

```html
<div id="GamePage" style="width:1920px; height:3840px; z-index=1;">

  <audio src="lib/Elements/click.mp3">Your browser does not support this audio html5 format</audio>
  <input id="Tap" type="image" src="lib/Elements/Tap%20here%20button.png" onclick="GameStart()" />
</div>
```

Comment: `var audioClick = document.getElementById("click");` , `x = document.getElementById('GameStar').offsetTop;` No elements having `id` `"click"` , or `"GameStar"`appear at `html`  at Question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable the button for the duration of the mp3 play, so that the users can not spam it. find out the length of the audio and disable the image button ( it would not accept any click.

You can use something like `setTimeout(function(){ //re enable your image button here }, 3000); // the 3000 ( is in miliseconds )`. In your onclick function GameStart. If you still want to have the user to spam it, then you might want to remove the loop , autoplay attributes and call currentTime=0 before everycall

```
function GameStart() {// I removed all other non-concerning code
  var audioClick = document.getElementById("click");
  audioClick.currentTime=0;
    audioClick.play();
}
```

Added the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/7hn8tkek/

Comment: what do you mean by disable the duration of the mp3 play? I need the audio to play in sync with the user continuous tap of the image button, meaning even if the user spam the image button

Comment: Then you should call   audioClick.stop();  before you should call audioClick.play();

Comment: I dont quite get your meaning? If I were to call .stop() before .play()?

Comment: I meant to stop whatever was playing, since you are calling the play method on click of the image, lets say the audio is already playing becuase of the earlier click action, and then you clicked again. so it should stop first ( sorry there is no stop method, you can try audioclick.currentTime=0 instead of stop() ) this way the audio resets.

Comment: Also I would assume the click is the audio element you are refering. Also remove the autoplay and loop

Comment: so that means it goes like that: `if (x < bottomStarLimit) {
    console.log("x:" + x);
    x = x + step; audioclick.currentTime=0;
    audioClick.play();
  }`

Comment: @Luke I have updated the answer, with a link , please have a look